# How to style text with a specific name in css

Tags: css, styling

I'm working on a theme for YouTube.

I have some video titles, and I want to change the specific color of only that video title, not all video titles on youtube.

Here's the code from YouTube:

```
<yt-formatted-string force-default-style="" class="style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer">Title here</yt-formatted-string>
```

I want to style only the title that has the name "Title here", so the text between the HTML.

Comment: Well, not really. I need a way to select the exact text between the HTML where it says "Title here" and that question doesn't really answer it. Plus I need a way to implement this in CSS not JavaScript or another programming language.

Comment: The question does answer it. It can't be done with CSS. Unless you just want *any* text that is there. If that's the case you can use `.ytd-video-primary-info-renderer { color: whatever color; }` More importantly, what have you tried to style this?

Comment: I've tried: `.ytd-video-primary-info-renderer[title*=video]`

Comment: Can you add a screenshoot and highlight which `title` you need to customize?